# Capture windows in wpf

Tags: wpf, windows, video

I am using WPF. I have background video (in mediaelement) and image with alpha channel.

I want to take video of the window.

I used this code which working great, but takes 50ms to frame

```
public static BitmapSource CopyWindow(Window window)
{
    int w , h;
    GetClientSize(window, out w, out h);
    RenderTargetBitmap targetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(w, h, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
    targetBitmap.Render(window);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

I need it to be much faster.

Any suggestions?

Thanks